# Fail to new an instance of gRPC.Core.Channel when code run in Partial Trust

Tags: c#, client, grpc, partial-trust

Grpc.Core.Channel is used call service. When code run in Partial Trust environment, an error below would pop up.

"Inheritance security rules violated by Type:'Grpc.Core.internal.SafeHandleZeroIsInvalid'
Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible"

How can I use Channel to call Grpc service on a partial trust environment? if can't, is there another way to call Grpc Service?

Look into gRPC code, a .net class SafeHandle is inherited by SafeHandleZeroIsInvalid. 
As official document described, for partially trusted code, it’s not allowed. InheritanceDemand of SafeHandle is: "for full trust for inheritors. This member cannot be inherited by partially trusted code."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=netframework-4.8

I had a try to create my own class which inherited from SafeHandle. And, I tryed to new an instance of this class.
When code run in Partial Trust, the same error pop up. 
What I am thinking the SafeHandle is the root reason cause this problem.

```
//the code is super simple, I just try to create a channel on a constructor. 
public class WriterClient
{
    private Channel _channel;
    private LoggingCenter _logger;
    public WriterClient(int port, ILogging logger)
    {
        _logger = logger == null? new LoggingCenter(new NullLogger()): new LoggingCenter(logger);
        //when run in Partial Trust, the code below will throw an exception.
        _channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1", port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);            
    }
```

What I am wanted is to call Grpc service correctly in Partial Trust. 
Any workaround for it?